# "Speak selected text" reads whole document in Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, high-sierra, text-to-speech

Recently I enabled *Speak selected text when key is pressed* feature in **Accessibility** menu.

It works well in Safari, Finder and other apps. But in Preview and other PDF readers like Skim, it acts wired. Although I selected a single word, it starts speaking from the first page of document, and if the first page contains only cover image, it says nothing. (silence)

It's **macOS High Sierra** with latest updates installed.

Comment: @user770: Nope, Do they have any bug reporting services?

Answer (score 1):

while the Preview is active select your text then on the top menue select "Edit" then select "Speech" then "Start speaking". You can create a keyboard shortcut for it by adding a shortcut key combination to the Keyboard in System Preferences:
 https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25377?locale=en_US